# Operate with a table in R

Tags: r, datatables

I want to get a tuple from a table in R.

For example, if i have this table named batch_task:

```
arrival_time, departure_time, jod_id, task_id
11792, 11999, 18, 88
11792, 14331, 18, 82
11792, 12112, 18, 91
16281, 16552, 27, 147
16281, 16396, 27, 139
16281, 16529, 27, 137
```

So, for each job_id i need a tuple `{arrival_time, service_time};` for example, for the job_id = 18, i want to get the tuple `{11792, (11999-11792)+(14331-11792)+(12112-11792)} = {11792, 3066}.`

Anyone could help me? Thanks in advance,
Jesús

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `batch_task` is actually a data frame rather than a table (which is a specific type of R structure dealing with count data), here's a solution using the `dplyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)

batch_task %>% 
  group_by(arrival_time) %>%
  summarise(service_time = sum(departure_time - arrival_time), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   arrival_time service_time
#>          <int>        <int>
#> 1        11792         3066
#> 2        16281          634
```

Note that there is no data structure called a tuple in R. There are various ways to represent tuples, but the most sensible way in this case would be to keep the result in a data frame format.

---

**Data**

```r
batch_task <- structure(list(arrival_time = c(11792L, 11792L, 11792L, 16281L, 
16281L, 16281L), departure_time = c(11999L, 14331L, 12112L, 16552L, 
16396L, 16529L), jod_id = c(18L, 18L, 18L, 27L, 27L, 27L), task_id = c(88L, 
82L, 91L, 147L, 139L, 137L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: why not `group_by` on `job_id` instead?

Answer (score 0):

With the data

```
batch_task <- structure(list(arrival_time = c(11792L, 11792L, 11792L, 16281L, 
16281L, 16281L), 
departure_time = c(11999L, 14331L, 12112L, 16552L, 
16396L, 16529L), 
jod_id = c(18L, 18L, 18L, 27L, 27L, 27L), 
task_id = c(88L, 
82L, 91L, 147L, 139L, 137L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I propose this solution

```
library(tidyverse)

batch_task %>% 
  mutate(service_time = departure_time - arrival_time) %>%
  group_by(jod_id, arrival_time) %>%     #assuming arrival_time is equal for each job_id
  summarise(service_time = sum(service_time))
```

Comment: @JesúsPérez, I'm glad that it helped.  Please upvote the solution(s) https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

Using `by`.

```
do.call(rbind, by(d, d$jod_id, function(x) {
  a <- x$arrival_time[1]
  c(a, sum(x$departure_time - a))
}))
#     [,1] [,2]
# 18 11792 3066
# 27 16281  634
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(arrival_time = c(11792L, 11792L, 11792L, 16281L, 
16281L, 16281L), departure_time = c(11999L, 14331L, 12112L, 16552L, 
16396L, 16529L), jod_id = c(18L, 18L, 18L, 27L, 27L, 27L), task_id = c(88L, 
82L, 91L, 147L, 139L, 137L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```